# We are using Airflow in dev environment. How to migrate changes from one environment to another environment?

Tags: migration, airflow

Currently DAG code is in a github and can be migrated to other environments easily. But what is the best way to migrate variables and connections to another environments?

We just browsed and found that we can do it through CLI but that is not working. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a DAG that uses the API to read variables and connections from dev and creates or updates them on the other environments.
[Airflow REST API Variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#tag/Variable)
[Airflow REST API Connections](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#tag/Connection)

In order to use the API, you need to activate [API authentication](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/api.html).